# select dropdown value matching to be case insensitive when prefilled

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

In Html template

```
<select [(ngModel)]="modelName">
  <option *ngFor="let ele of elements" [value]="element">{{ele}}</option>
</select>
```

In .ts file

```
this.elements = ['ABCd', 'mnOp'];
this.modelName = 'Abcd';
```

I Expect the value of the modelName 'ABCd' to be preselected from the list.

Currently nothing is displayed in the Select box though the modelName contains value 'Abcd'

Comment: You're setting the value to `element` but you are doing a loop on `ele of elements`. You're also going to want to convert your elements and match case to lower case before the comparison if you want it to be case insensitive.

Comment: ya that's a typo mistake , [value]="ele"

Answer (score 0):

The select's value is `undefined` because `element` is undefined so it is not able to match to the string `'Abcd'`. To make the values lowcase I would map your element values to an object.

Should be:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="modelName">
    <option *ngFor="let ele of elements" [value]="ele.value">{{ele.label}}</option> 
</select>
```

In the component:

```js
this.elements = ['ABCd', 'mnOp'].map((v) => ({ value: v.toLowerCase(), label: v }));

this.modelName = 'abcd';
```

Comment: In my case elements and modelName both are dynamically coming from service, I need to make the comparision case Insensitive

Comment: according to your solution, map method will change the values of array to lower case, but the requirement is not to change the case, only the comparision be insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Like teddy said, the strings compared between the 'select' value and the 'element' values are **case-sensitive.** You can either copy the value from the first element manually or, since you already conveniently have the array in your code, assign the first element of the array directly to your model. This way if for some reason the array is created dynamically you won't have to worry about finding the value;

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="modelName">
    <option *ngFor="let ele of elements" [value]="ele">{{ele}}</option> 
</select>
```

TS

```
this.elements = ['ABCd', 'mnOp'];
this.modelName = this.elements[0];
```

**EDIT**

Based on what you've said I believe the best solution for you is indeed to change the case of the variables. Angular provides a couple pipes to do so. This method requires that you split the *two-way binding* up, and create two different fields for *property binding* and *event binding*. See below:

HTML

```
<select 
    [ngModel]="modelName | uppercase"
    (change)="modelName = $event" >
    <option *ngFor="let ele of elements" [value]="ele | uppercase">
        {{ele}}
    </option> 
</select>
```

Hope this helps someone. Good Luck!

Comment: both elements and modelName are recieved from response dynamically